# powershell Select-String Inquiry

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am attempting to parse a text document for a pattern with the goal of eliminating the pattern and its previous line. This command-line confirms to me that I am selecting the desired data:

```
Get-Content -Path '.\460-est-5.txt' | Select-String -Pattern "THE PREVIOUS" SimpleMatch -AllMatches -Context 1,0
```

Since I wish to eliminate this and redirect the output, I generate this command, and it queries nothing:

```
Get-Content -Path '.\460-est-5.txt' | Select-String -Pattern "THE PREVIOUS"     -SimpleMatch -NotMatch -AllMatches -Context 1,0
```

However when I eliminate `-Context 1,0` it queries almost all the data I need, obviously leaving in the lines before I want out.

`-Context 1,0` has been defeating `-NotMatch`, and I have dug through the help files, MSDN, StackOverflow, and I am at the point of seeing if I can create a script but it won't matter because I need both of the params `-NotMatch` and `-Context` (at least to my knowledge!).

I apologize for the lack of knowledge. I am new to PowerShell and appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thank you for your time!

Original data:

### A0000   FMC        18001 0000  18009 0820    200.3

### A0000   TRAN       18001 0000  00000 0000    744.0

### *****  THE PREVIOUS STATUS IS NON-REPORTABLE  *****

### A0000   FMC        18031 1600  00000 0000      8.0

### A0000   PMCM       18031 1200  18031 1600      4.0

### A0000   FMC        18017 1303  18031 1200    334.9

### A0000   NMCM       18017 0700  18017 1303      6.1

### A0000   FMC        18001 0000  18017 0700    391.0

### A0000   TRAN       18001 0000  00000 0000    744.0

### *****  THE PREVIOUS STATUS IS NON-REPORTABLE  *****

### A0000   FMC        18017 2200  00000 0000    338.0

### A0000   PMCM       18017 1410  18017 2200      7.8

Modified data:

### A0000   FMC        18001 0000  18009 0820    200.3

### A0000   FMC        18031 1600  00000 0000      8.0

### A0000   PMCM       18031 1200  18031 1600      4.0

### A0000   FMC        18017 1303  18031 1200    334.9

### A0000   NMCM       18017 0700  18017 1303      6.1

### A0000   FMC        18001 0000  18017 0700    391.0

### A0000   FMC        18017 2200  00000 0000    338.0

### A0000   PMCM       18017 1410  18017 2200      7.8

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [MCVE]. You also need to format your code.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for the format suggest, my apologies!

Comment: No worries, you haven't been around long enough to be expected to know that!

Comment: Do you want to remove only the pattern from a line, and the whole line before that? Or drop both lines? It would be useful if you could show some data coming in, and what the desired output should look like.

Comment: Can you attach a sample of what your are trying to parse, and what you are trying to make it look like after running the script?

Comment: Janne Tuukkanen & HeedfulCrayon: I apologize for the delayed response work has been hectic! I am trying to remove the whole line and the line before. Select-String has been successful in removing the whole line but the parameters conflict, and to my knowledge after reading the help files they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to do it (by a long shot), but you could try this:

```
$filePath = ".\460-est-5.txt"
$query = "THE PREVIOUS"

& {
    $currentLine = $null
    $lastLine = $null

    Get-Content -Path $filePath |% {
        $lastLine = $currentLine
        $currentLine = $_

        if ($currentLine -eq $query) {
            $currentLine = $null
            return
        }

        return $lastLine
    }

    if ($currentLine) {
        return $currentLine
    }
} |? { $_ -ne $null } |% {
    $_
}
```